# Rails - data view from has_many and Has_many_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, relationships

I'm trying to implement this project:

http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/cnb46ti2/relationships.png

- I want to let view the skills of an employee on the employee's show page
- An employee has a position, and every position has skills which an employee of this position needs to know
- so if I understand right, positions and skills have an n:m relationship, and they need a join table for a has_many_and_belongs_to_many relationship. Because a position includes many skills and every skill belongs to many positions.

now my questions

1. the position_skill-table -> is it better to use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, so this table has no own id or is it better to use a has_many :through relationship? I guess it's better do use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, because this relationship table will not have any further information inside than just the two keys. Am I right?
2. if I take a has_and_belongs_to_many - relationship, is that the only thing I need to write into the models?

a) `class Position < ActiveRecord :: Base (...) has_and_belongs_to_many :skills (...)`

b) `class Skill < ActiveRecord :: Base (...) has_and_belongs_to_many :positions (...)`

c) into db\migrate `def self.up create_table :positon_skill, :id => false do |t| (...)`
and after that, the positions and skills are connected with each other? Is that right? Did I forget something?

- if that's right, how can I let the skills view on employee's show page? An employee has 1 position, and this position has several skills... What for code do I need to write into the show.html.erb of employee? Something like `<%= employee.position.skill %>`? Do I also need to render something? Sorry, I'm very confused and I think I read too much information in web... Or is there any description in web which exactly describes what I need for?

thanks alot in advance and sorry for that redundant question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you're sure you aren't going to want to add any information later to the `position_skills` table, `has_and_belongs_to_many` will work fine. However, `has_many :through` is far more flexible if you change your mind later and isn't much harder to set up.
2. If you use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you only need association declarations in the models and the database table with `position_id:integer` and `skill_id:integer` fields. Seems like you've got that already.

To be able to access `employee.position.skills` in your view, you need to eagerly load the employee's associations. Try something like the following:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id], :include => { :position => :skills })
  end
  ...
end
```

I think that should work if you stick with `has_and_belongs_to_many`, but if you go for `has_many :through` (which I recommend), you'll need to use `:include => { :position => { :position_skills => :skills } }`

Comment: @Luke: 
Thanksalot for this detailed answer! Sadly, it didn't work well with has_and_belongs_to_many. That's what I did after I created all the other tables and their relations 

1. I created position_skills (with `rails generate scaffold position_skill position_id:integer skill_id:integer`)

2. I added `:id => false` into the routes\create_position_skill 

3. I used the command `rake db:migrate` so it didn't create the id 

4. I filled the table position_skill in SQLite DatabaseBrowser

5. Then I wanted to try out if positions and skills are really related to each other

Comment: so I wrote into rails console `first_skill = Skill.first` (which worked of course) and `first_skill.positions` which occured an error: `ActiveRecord :: Statement Invalid: Could not find table positions_skills` -> seems like it doesn't find the table although it's migrated. But I'm wondering: Why does it search "positions_skills" and not "position_skills"?

Comment: another question referred to the method wih has_and_belongs_to_many: 

I don't need to write anything into the model of position_skills? Nothing like `belongs_to :position belongs_to :skill`?

Comment: If you're using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you shouldn't create anything for `positions_skills` except the table in the database. You can run `rails destroy scaffold position_skill` to get rid of all of all that and recreate the migration (using the correct `positions_skills` table name). Everything is handled behind the scenes in Rails for `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships, you just need to provide it with the proper database table. That should also answer your second question: there is no model.

Comment: Also: You basically did everything you need to do for a `has_many :through` association. If you want to, you could just redeclare it as such instead of deleting everything you did.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like in your diagram. Consider the following:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to :position
  ...
end

class Position < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :position_skills
  has_many :skills, :through => :position_skills
  ...
end    

class PositionSkill < ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to :position
  belongs_to :skill
  ...
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_many :position_skills
  has_many :positions, :through => :position_skills
  ...
end
```

The only problem with this is that an employee is tied to a single position. While this position has many skills through positions. I would change it to position `belongs_to` employee and employee `has_many` positions. This leaves it open to track employees that move from one position to the next. Let me know if you need further info on that.

Comment: great, that worked perfectly! I also added the code into the employee controller. In a funny case, the code which was meant for **has_and_belongs_to_many** `:include => { :position => :skills }` works, and the code which was suggested for the **has_many :through** - Method `:through 
:include => { :position => { :position_skills => :skills } }` first gave me an error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError --- Association named 'skills' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`, but I changed the :skills into :skill, and now it works.

Comment: but now also for this case a further question: 
my view now looks like this after I used `<%= @employee.position.skills %>`

[link]http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/p2rjbbev/viewskills.PNG

Of course I just want to let view 'Skill 1' , 'Skill 2', 'Skill 4' instead of all this useless information. Do I need another command instead of `<%= @employee.position.skills %>` for getting this result? Something like `@employee.position.skills :select => category`?? I really have no Idea!